# Published naming conflict best practices? Quickbooks allows customer account names to be the same as reserved account type names

Tags: python, quickbooks

This problem is specific to QuickBooks account naming, but It's so oddly specific that I want to ask this question in a more general way.  I know that name conflicts happen all the time when enterprises are managing data conversions, so I'm hoping that some best practices for name conflicts are available for guidance.  Names are VERY important.

The business layer of my code uses the account name as a dictionary key to access data.  That's how most accountants and humans think about this world, so it's important to maintain:

```
global accounts
accounts['Fixed Assets'].data
```

Leave it to Intuit to make this weird...

When a QuickBooks user is creating an account, the default account name is occasionally the same as a reserved account type name.  I'll provide an example:

"Fixed Assets" is a reserved account type: which means it shows up on balance sheet reports as a section in a specific order.  When there are sub-accounts, the section header starts with "Fixed Assets", then indents and shows the user account names, and ends with "Total Fixed Assets".  Here's where it gets weird.

The user account names can be the same as the reserved account type!  QuickBooks does not prevent the user from having a user account name that is exactly the same as the category which that account is in.  So the report looks like this:

```
Assets
   ... other sections ...
   Fixed Assets                   #<== reserved type header
      user account 1      $100
      user account 2      $100
      Fixed Assets                #<== huh... weird
         Vehicles         $100
         Tools            $100
      Total Fixed Assets  $200    #<== oh good lord...
   Total Fixed Assets     $400    #<== facepalm
Total Assets
```

So the first "Total Fixed Assets" is the summation of user subaccounts under the user account "Fixed Assets".  The second "Total Fixed Assets" is the summation of all accounts with the "Fixed Assets" type.  The only delineation on the report is the indentation, which implies hierarchy.

**Here's Where I've tried to find the answer:**
The Intuit QBO API doesn't have an answer.  All objects they return are either reports which follow the convention above or objects that contain the name and type in separate fields.
https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/balancesheet
https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/account

The API for Journal entries only requires the account name... but you would only ever interact with the user account name in a Journal entry... because accounting: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/journalentry

**Ideas:**
Option 1: I could pre-pend a special character "cn" (customer name or conflicting name) to any user account name that conflicts with a reserved type... this requires some pretty active name management, but it's doable.  For the user:

```
accounts['cnFixed Assets']
accounts['Fixed Assets']
```

Meh... it's OK, the default use will be OK since when a user selects "Fixed Assets" the will usually want the one that they get.  This will cause some confusion and require specific documentation.

Option 2:
Require that the user always specifies the type based on an enum

```
class AccountType(Enum)
   FIXED_ASSETS = x
   CURRENT_ASSETS = y

accounts('Fixed Assets',AccountType.FIXED_ASSETS)
```

ugh... this loses the dictionary like feel and intent.  Plus, when I get data from non-quickbooks based accounting systems that have different reserved types, then what?

Option 3:
Prepend the type to bad actors

```
account['Fixed Assets:Fixed Assets']  # ':' is the standard account delineator used by quickbooks.
```

This conflicts with QuickBooks' sub-account delineation standards.  In the chart of accounts, the example above would have `"Fixed Assets:Vehicles"` and `"Fixed Assets:Tools"` in it per their standard.  This approach would make that inconsistent since `"Fixed Assets:Vehicles"` would need to become `"Fixed Assets:Fixed Assets:Vehicles"`.
(`accountname:subaccountname` vs `type:accountname:subaccountname`)

Plus, when I get data from a non-quickbooks system, these will be different.

Option 4:  prepend the type to ALL accounts... basically Option 3 but nuclear.
This causes issues with the user... and when I get data from non-quickbooks accounting systems this will cause issues with differences in account types.

**Help:**

Has anyone run into this specific issue with Quickbooks?  `<I'm not holding my breath>` How did you solve it?

Is there a best practice standard that would provide some guidance here?  I know that there are reserved name conflicts that happen all the time when interfacing between systems.  Does anyone have some ways they dealt with these kinds of conflicts and have a solution that you don't hate?

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of good information in your question, but it's not clear to me which specific use-case you need to solve for. If you're giving users the option of selecting an account from a list that could have duplicate account names, the use of colons or indentation to list the hierarchy of each account (and therefore differentiate it) is a conventional standard (see other apps that integrate with QuickBooks Online and display the QuickBooks account list; Bill.com, Hubdoc, etc.).

You also mention passing these account names as unique identifiers when creating journal entries with the API - is this a separate use case, or is it related to the first one I addressed above? If this refers to a separate backend function that doesn't directly involve your users, I recommend using an account's internal id, rather than its name value, as its unique identifier in API calls. Using account names (or any user-editable field) for backend functions is risky because users often modify any of those values they can, which could then cause your code to behave in ways you had not intended.